# Test of lot of math operations in a class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, math

Is there a way of testing functions inside a class in an easy way for correct results? I mean, I have been looking at google test unit testing, but seems more to find fails in the work classes and functions, more than in the expected result.

For example, from math theory one could know which is the square root of all numbers, now you want to check a sqrt function, seeking for floating point precision errors, and then you also want to check lot of functions that use floats and look for any precision error, is there a way to make this easy and fast ?

Comment: "seems more to find fails in the work classes and functions, more than in the expected result" - I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: How about an 'oracle' that generates (possibly random) data and answers to various function calls, and then feeds this information to the system under test, which calls the appropriate functions and checks results. Calling the right function is going to be the part where you will manually have to map function names to actual functions, otherwise this should be easy this way.

Comment: sorry @OliCharlesworth it's my english, I don't know how to tell well what I meant. I think is easy for checking for example if one bool yoou expect it true or false, or an array index to be between 0 and 'n', like an assert but with more posibilities. But how could you test a precision issue of floats, if you tell google-test the expected result also using the same "float math" with the same precision issues?

Comment: are you writing your own math functions or testing like cmath. if your writing your own math methods then you can refine the precision of the  returns by probably refining the number of expressions in your taylor series, but if your doing this on like cmath classes then you will need to have some known test values, and run compares on those

Comment: I not making my own functions, then I could compare them to the standard ones at least, but using float math inside functions that make other things, and expecting a more or less precise results, and that nothing goes wrong because precision errors. I dont know if unit testing can be applied to things like that or is something you have to do trying a lot and checking results manually.

Comment: so do you want to throw a number at like a cmath method and then know that it is right to a certain degree, or do you want to just use some math operations in your function, and then have a desired result?

Comment: Yes, I want to test functions that make extensive use of cmath operations, mainly using floats, and then check that the final result is desirable and the precision valid, without rounding errors, without NaN and infinite floats, and with correct comparations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 direct solutions

1)

one of the easiest ways to test for accuracy of mathematical functions is similar to what is used as definition work for limits in calculus. taking the value to be tested, and then also using a value that is "close" on both sides. I have heard of analogies drawn between limit analysis and unit testing, but keep in mind that if your looking for speed this will not be your best options. and that this will only work on continues operations, and that this analogy is for definition work only

so what you would do is have a "limitDomain" variable defined per function (this is because some operations are more accurate then others for reasoning look up taylor approximation of [function]), and then use that as you limiter. then test: low, high, and then the value itself, and then take the avg of all three within a given margin of error,

```
float testMathOpX(float _input){
    float low = 0.0f;
    float high = 0.0f;

    low = _input - limitDomainOpX;
    high = _input + limitDomainOpX;

    low = OpX(low);
    _input = OpX(_input);
    high = OpX(high);

    // doing 3 separate averages with division by 2 mains the worst decimal you will have is a trailing 5, or in some cases a trailing 25
    low = (low + _input)/2
    high = (_input + high)/2;
    _input = (low + high)/2
    return _input;
}
```

2)

the other method that I can think of is more of a table of values approach being that you take the input, and then check to see where on the domain of the operation it lies, and if it lies within certain values then you use value replacement. The thing to realize is that you need to have a lot of work ahead of time to get these table of values, and then it becomes just domain testing of the value your taking in in the form of:

```
if( (_input > valLow) && (_input < valHigh)){
     ... replace the value with an empirically found value
}
```

the problem with this is that you need o find those empirically found values.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have requirements on the precision or do you want to find the precision?
If it is the former, then it is not hard to create test cases using any test framework.

```
y = myfunc(x);
if (y > expected_y + allowed_error || y < expected_y - allowed_error) {
  // Test failed
  ...
}
```

**Edit:** 
There are two routes to finding the precision, through testing and through algorithm analysis.

Testing should be straightforward: Compare the output with the correct values (which you have to obtain in some way).

Algortithm analysis is when you calculate the expected size of the error by calculating the error of the algorithm and the error caused by lack of precision in floating point arithmetic.

Comment: I want to find the precision, find for what range of input values function gives the more precise results, and if there are some lonely input value that makes the function to behave with unexpected/bad result

Comment: In that case you won't get much help from the normal test frameworks.

Comment: Any idea of some library or framework that could do that ? Thank you for reply, and the edit, very useful, put me in right direction for looking for